# Faster I/O function than fgets

Tags: c, performance, io

I am writing an interpreter in C and am currently working on the lexer. I read in the source file content line by line using fgets.

However, on my computer, it takes about 8 seconds to read a file with 100,000 lines with 50 characters each while it takes 0.2 seconds to read a file with 10 lines with 50,0000 characters each (increasing the length of the line doesn't really change anything). I assume this is due to fgets being slow. I did write my own line-by-line-reader, but I got the same results.

The interpreter has to handle big files, so reading the entire file into a buffer is not really an option. So, I am now asking if anybody has any better ideas for going through these files. It would of course be nice if the solution was platform-independent, but if it isn't I can probably work around that.

Comment: It would be easy enough to memory map the entire file, then look for line breaks with `memchr()`.  Do note that the first line break might be at the end of the file.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I think this is exactly what I was looking for! I thought of doing this previously, but didn't think it was possible (or rather supported)! I suppose I should read up on the library functions...

Comment: It's going to depend on your operating system.  It's normally `mmap` but there is a different API on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, I am already working on implementing it on both Windows and POSIX. Thank you for the suggestion, once again!

Comment: " I assume this is due to fgets being slow" --> My money is that this is incorrect and that the bottle neck is in the _unposted_ lexer.

Comment: @chux Do you also think that the unpostedness of the lexer makes it slower? We'll see if the lexer is slow when I get my file mapping solution completed :).

Comment: Had this post contained a stripped down version of code that replicated the problem and could be compiled and ran by others, that would have led to a speedy and quality answer.  As is, we are left with making educated guesses.

Comment: What sort of disk drive are you using? Is the file network mounted? What sort of computer are you using? I created a program to count the lines in two files matching your description, using a fixed size buffer of 100,000 bytes (plenty big enough), and got radically different results. Granted, I'm on a MacBook Pro (2015 model) with an SSD drive, so the files may still be in memory, but the times I got were 11 ms for the 100,000 short lines and 5 ms for 10 long lines. These are multiple orders of magnitude faster than what you're reporting, so there must be something dramatically different.

Comment: @chux Sorry for being a total jerk yesterday, I have slept and have successfully found out the problem. As you said, fgets isn't the problem, it is actually incredibly fast (for some reason I didn't think of testing to find out where my code bottlenecked yesterday). It turns out that printf is the problem (I used it for bug testing). I can now process 10 million lines in a fraction of a second now that I have removed the printf from my code! Sorry, once again, you were correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is because fgets is line oriented.  This means that fgets is invoked only 10 times in your 0.2 second example, and fgets is invoked 100,000 times in the other example.

So, in your "fast" example you only suffer the overhead associated with 10 function calls.  In the slower example you suffer the overhead of 100,000 function calls.

fgets is pretty fast in processing a line, even very long lines.  The time spent inside of fgets is extremely minimal compared to the time to invoke the fgets function.  So, fewer invocations of fgets will produce the result you see as most of the "overhead" is in calling fgets, not in what fgets does.

Comment: I wouldn't think that the function overhead would be that big.

Comment: @Zyphicx: It's not just function overhead, but it's also locking a mutex and doing various bookkeeping operations on the FILE struct.

Comment: It turned out that this isn't the problem. fgets is incredibly fast, you can read more about my solution in my other comment.